# How to share text with markdown syntax to telegram?

Tags: android, telegram

I want to share my text from my app to telegram with text style like bold, underline, etc. But result is raw text instead formatted text message.

```
void shareToTelegram(String msg)
{
    final String appName = "org.telegram.messenger";
    final boolean isAppInstalled = isAppAvailable(getApplicationContext(), appName);
    if (isAppInstalled)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        myIntent.setPackage(appName);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);//
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with"));
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Telegram not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and this is my text

```
**Branch**  : `branch`
**XXX**  : `abc`
**XXX**  : `25/10/2019`
**XXX**  : `31/10/2019`
**XXX**   : `Poster A3`
**XXX**   : `haloo`
**XXX**   : `JPG`
**XXX**   : `url`
**XXX**   : `haloo`
**XXX**    : `https://url`
```

when i copied my text and paste in my telegram. the result is nice. but when i try to share it, the result is the raw text. is there any solution to this? Thanks

Comment: `myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString()));
sendIntent.setType("text/html");`

Comment: @RakeshKumar not working sir